# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED got by fetch data with ReactJS && ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

Hi I am working on a class group project and I am responsible for the front-end part. I am a rookie in front-end so I may have made stupid mistakes.
After I got codes in back-end from my partner:

```
[ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IDBManager_Users _usersManager;

        public AccountController(IDBManager_Users usersManager)
        {
            _usersManager = usersManager;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Account/Create")]
        public bool CreateUser(User user)
        {
            bool created = _usersManager.CreateUser(user);

            return created;
        }
```

And I put a fetching data request in React to create a user:

```
    register= e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(`http://localhost:5001/Account/Create`, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                userRole: this.state.userRole,
                country: this.state.country,
                place: this.state.place,
                city: this.state.city
            })
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if(response){
                    this.props.history.push('/login')
                }
                else{
                    alert('Please Register with Correct Info!');
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
```

I think all other parts go well and I can get my request payload from Chrome like:
`{"email":"abc@gmail.com","password":"abc","userRole":"1","country":"United States","place":"NY","city":"whatever"}`
but fail with:
`POST http://localhost:5001/Account/Create net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
I do not know what kind of stupid I have made but I really struggled into it.
Waiting for reponse :)
Edit1: If you want to have a look of startup.cs, I have attach it here:

```
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(SqlManager), new SqlManager(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
             services.AddCors(options =>
    {
          options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                builder =>
            {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
    });
            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method signature to map the JSON from the body of the request to the actual DTO object using the FromBody annotation:

```
public bool CreateUser([FromBody] User user)
```

Please note that since you didn't provided the code from the Startup.cs I have no idea if something else is missing there in regards of the routing and authorization.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute

Comment: I added the FromBody signature but it did not work. I have also attached my startup.cs codes. Thank you.

Comment: @TailinLyu, I think that the problem is that you are trying to connect using HTTP, but in the startup.cs you have "UseHttpsRedirection()", so it is forcing a redirect using HTTPS. Comment that out and try again. It may also be that you're using a wrong port, make sure that the application is reachable using that port.